# NancyFx bind TimeSpan is not Working json

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-binding, nancy

Good Morning (here)

I'm using NancyFx and i've a problem when i try to bind a class with TimeSpan Properties, i'm using AngularJs too

a json that i use is:

> {
>      "description": "foo",
>      "scheduleTime": {
>           "days": 0,
>           "hours": 23,
>           "minutes": 36,
>           "seconds": 10,
>           "milliseconds": 0
>      }
>   };

My C# Class

```
public class Scheduler
{
    public int IDHorario{ get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public Nullable<TimeSpan> scheduleTime{ get; set; }
}
```

My Nancy Module

```
Post["/Add"] = parameters =>
{
    var sch= this.Bind<Scheduler>();

    HorarioDB.CreateHorario(sch);

    return new Response().WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
};
```

But i'm receiving scheduleTime null, i don't know Why ?? :'(

Any idea ??

Thanks A lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Json/Converters/TimeSpanConverter.cs), the TimeSpan json converter handles only TimeSpan, not nullable TimeSpan.

You can file an issue for Nancy, or even better, provide an fix - it's an open source projects, and contrubutions are welcome.

For the time being, consider using non-nullable property on your class.

Or, create your own JavaScriptConverter and register it. See how the [TimeSpan converter was born](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/336) for implementation details. You can reuse the existing one, just verify if there is incoming data. Something like:

```
public override IEnumreable<Type> SupportedTypes
{
   get
   {
      return new[]{typeof(Nullable<TimeSpan>)};
}
public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
{
   if (dictionary.Count == 0)
   {
      return null;
   }
   return new TimeSpanConverter().Deserialize(dictionary, type, serializer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Friend, i will work hardly for to upload a good thing.